# Ubuntu on Azure: increase partition size

Tags: ubuntu, partition, fdisk, resize2fs

I have basic unix skills and have to do some maintenance on a linux machine (Ubuntu 18.04). hosted on Azure. I need to resize the /dev/sda1 partition, giving more space to it.

When I run `df -h` it outputs:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           796M  896K  795M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        29G   24G  5.8G  81% /
tmpfs           3.9G  8.0K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda15      105M  3.4M  102M   4% /boot/efi
/dev/sdc1       118G   14G   99G  12% /opt/apps
/dev/sdb1        16G   45M   15G   1% /mnt
tmpfs           796M     0  796M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Which is the proper/better way to increase /dev/sda1, using space from /dev/sdc1 (or sdb1)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to resize the OS Disk on the VM from Azure portal.

Go To **Home** > **Virtual Machines** > in **Setting** section > Select **Disk** > Select **OS Disk** > Select the **Configuration**

Enter the value of partition (In GB) you required.

**Note** : Increase the OS Disk space will required the VM State **Stopped (deallocated)**

Now, Start the VM and check the "/" partition. It will show the Increased Value.